# Why elapsed time is less than the slot time consumed in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have gone through many of the google cloud blogs and bigquery documentation to understand what is elapsed time and slot time consumed in bigquery. Here I had run one query which has the following output

[image]

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442891/bigquery-elapsed-time-or-slot-time-consumed-which-is-a-better-measure) , 'elapsed time' is total time taken by BQ to execute your query. 'slot time' is the total time taken by vCPUs to execute your query.  I still had a doubt about how **the total time of the query is lesser than CPU time of the query if my understanding was correct**. I have gone through this [blog](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation). Still didn't get the clarity. Since everywhere slot time will be described as the CPU and other resources metric, can I take this [metric](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobStatistics.QueryStatistics#com_google_cloud_bigquery_JobStatistics_QueryStatistics_getTotalSlotMs__) as CPU time spent by this query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below naive and super simple analogy - hope it helps to clear things a little

You hired 10 workers - they worked as a team for 1 hour

While for you work looked like was done in a one hour  - in reality there were 10 man/hours spent

So the 1 hour you see  - is `elapsed time` or `total query time`
While 10 hours is - `slot time consumed` or `CPU time`

Answer (score 1):

The `slot time` typically exceeds the `elapsed time` as there are many workers involved in executing a query in bigquery.  Each worker spends `slot time`.  For example, a dozen workers at 50% CPU, as they are also doing I/O, can spend 6 seconds of `slot time` per second of `elapsed time`.

[The docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-overview#query_processing) reference "workers in parralel".

Many of my queries run less than a minute of `elapsed time` and use over an hour of `slot time`.